# understanding links in an asp classic site

Tags: hyperlink, asp-classic

I am working on an existing asp classic site and there are links that work but I don't understand how they are working. I have a link /shoponline/threads/threadreg and when I look at the site structure, there isn't a /shoponline/threads folder, but there is a /shoponline/thread.asp page and there is a /shoponline/threadT.asp page. There are a few examples like this on the site where the link ends in a plural like /shoponline/fabrics but the file it points to seems to be /shoponline/fabric.asp. Can someone explain how this link works?

Comment: It's called [`URL Rewrite module`](https://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module) and it's built into IIS 7 and above.

Comment: Take a look at your web.config file